# How can I mix & match my properties in <p>?

Tags: vue.js

I have a `<p v-for="index in attrLength" :key="index" class="text-3xl"></p>`. The idea is to take an object, in this case `const project = projects[index]` put it inside the `<p>` tag, add a `.` to it, and add the `index` number after that from the loop, but with the letter "p" injected in front of it, so you'd end up with `project.p1`, `project.p2` and so on, inside the double curly braces like so: `<p v-for="index in attrLength" :key="index" class="text-3xl">{{project.p1}}</p>`.

How do I do that? I didn't find anything in the docs. Is this even possible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [bracket notation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Property_accessors#bracket_notation) with computed object keys:

```html
<p v-for="index in attrLength" :key="index" class="text-3xl">
  {{ project[`p${index}`] }}
</p>
```

[demo](https://stackblitz.com/edit/vue3-bracket-notation-to-compute-keys?file=src%2Fcomponents%2FMyComponent.vue)

Answer (score 0):

I am assuming `attrLength` is a number. Hence, as iteration will always start from `1` inside `v-for` loop. You can access project objects by using `projects[index - 1]` instead of `projects[index]`.

Live Demo **:**

```js
new Vue({
  el: '#app',
  data: {
    projects: [{
        p1: 'Paragraph 1'
    }, {
        p2: 'Paragraph 2'
    }]
  }
})
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vue/2.5.17/vue.js"></script>
<div id="app">
  <p v-for="index in 2" :key="index" class="text-3xl">
    {{ projects[index - 1][`p${index}`] }}
  </p>
</div>
```